# Create side-by-side environments in Latex

Tags: latex, pdflatex, cls

I am trying to create three environments that are beside one another and do not fill the entire page as seen in the attached image. Within each environment, I am trying to add the cvref function, attached is the necessary cls code.

test.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\@ifl@t@r\fmtversion{2018/04/01}{\UseRawInputEncoding}{}
\ProvidesClass{altacv}[2018/07/27 AltaCV v1.1.4, yet another alternative class for a résumé/curriculum vitae.]
\newif\if@academicons
\DeclareOption{academicons}{\@academiconstrue}
%% v1.1.3: Choice of round/square photo
\newif\if@normalphoto
\DeclareOption{normalphoto}{\@normalphototrue}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{extarticle}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{extarticle}

\RequirePackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{fontawesome}

%% v1.1: Optionally load academicons
\if@academicons
  %% Patch to make academicons compilable with XeLaTeX
  \ExplSyntaxOn
  \msg_redirect_name:nnn { fontspec } { font-not-found } { none }
  \ExplSyntaxOff
  \RequirePackage{academicons}
  \newfontfamily{\AI}{academicons.ttf}
\fi

\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{accent}{blue!70!black}
\colorlet{heading}{black}
\colorlet{emphasis}{black}
\colorlet{body}{black!80!white}
\newcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\newcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\RequirePackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=*,labelsep=0.5em,nosep,itemsep=0.25\baselineskip,after=\vskip0.25\baselineskip}
\setlist[itemize]{label=\itemmarker}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{dashrule}
\RequirePackage{multirow,tabularx}
\RequirePackage{changepage}
% \RequirePackage{marginfix}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\divider}{\textcolor{body!30}{\hdashrule{\linewidth}{0.6pt}{0.5ex}}\medskip}

\newenvironment{fullwidth}{%
  \begin{adjustwidth}{}{\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax}}
  {\end{adjustwidth}}

\newcommand{\emailsymbol}{\faAt}
\newcommand{\phonesymbol}{\faPhone}
\newcommand{\homepagesymbol}{\faChain}
\newcommand{\locationsymbol}{\faMapMarker}
\newcommand{\linkedinsymbol}{\faLinkedin}
\newcommand{\twittersymbol}{\faTwitter}
\newcommand{\githubsymbol}{\faGithub}
\newcommand{\orcidsymbol}{\aiOrcid}
\newcommand{\mailsymbol}{\faEnvelope}

\newcommand{\printinfo}[2]{\mbox{\textcolor{accent}{\normalfont #1}\hspace{0.5em}#2\hspace{2em}}}
\newcommand{\weblinks}[3]{\mbox{\textcolor{accent}{\normalfont #1}\hspace{0.5em}{\href{#2}{#3}}\hspace{2em}}}
\newcommand{\name}[1]{\def\@name{#1}}
\newcommand{\tagline}[1]{\def\@tagline{#1}}
\newcommand{\photo}[2]{\def\@photo{#2}\def\@photodiameter{#1}}
\newcommand{\email}[2]{\weblinks{\emailsymbol}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\mailaddress}[1]{\printinfo{\mailsymbol}{#1}}
\newcommand{\phone}[1]{\printinfo{\phonesymbol}{#1}}
\newcommand{\homepage}[2]{\weblinks{\homepagesymbol}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\twitter}[1]{\printinfo{\twittersymbol}{#1}}
\newcommand{\linkedin}[2]{\weblinks{\linkedinsymbol}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\github}[2]{\weblinks{\githubsymbol}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\orcid}[1]{\printinfo{\orcidsymbol}{#1}}
\newcommand{\location}[1]{\printinfo{\locationsymbol}{#1}}
   
\newcommand{\cvsection}[2][]{%
  \bigskip%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{}{}{\marginpar{\vspace*{\dimexpr1pt-\baselineskip}\raggedright\input{#1}}}%
  {\color{heading}\LARGE\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#2}}\\[-1ex]%
  {\color{heading}\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}\par}\medskip
}

\newcommand{\cvref}[4]{%
  \smallskip
  \textcolor{emphasis}{\textbf{#1}}\par
  \smallskip\normalsize
  \ifstrequal{#2}{}{}{
  \textbf{\color{accent}#2}\par
  \smallskip}
  \begin{description}[font=\color{accent},style=multiline,leftmargin=1.25em]
  \item[\small\normalfont\mailsymbol] #3
  \item[\small\normalfont\phonesymbol] #4
  \end{description}
  \medskip
%   \medskip
}


\newenvironment{cvcolumn}[1]{\begin{minipage}[t]{#1}\raggedright}{\end{minipage}}

\RequirePackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
%% For removing numbering entirely when using a numeric style
% \setlength{\bibhang}{1em}
% \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\makebox[\bibhang][l]{\itemmarker}}
% \setlength{\biblabelsep}{0pt}
\defbibheading{pubtype}{\cvsubsection{#1}}
\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\makebox[\bibhang][l]{\itemmarker}}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.25\baselineskip}

% v1.1.2: make it easier to add a sidebar aligned with top of next page
\RequirePackage{afterpage}
\newcommand{\addsidebar}[2][]{\marginpar{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{}{}{\vspace*{#1}}%
  \input{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\addnextpagesidebar}[2][]{\afterpage{\addsidebar[#1]{#2}}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \color{body}
  \raggedright
}
```

It is called in the following snippet:

test.tex

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{altacv}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=9cm,marginparwidth=6.8cm,marginparsep=1.2cm,top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm,footskip=2\baselineskip}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[default]{lato}
\definecolor{Mulberry}{HTML}{72243D}
\definecolor{SlateGrey}{HTML}{2E2E2E}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{666666}
\colorlet{heading}{Sepia}
\colorlet{accent}{Mulberry}
\colorlet{emphasis}{SlateGrey}
\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}
\renewcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\renewcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{fullwidth}
    \cvsection{References}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{flushleft}
            \cvref{test}{test}{\href {mailto:test}{test}}{test}
        \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
            \cvref{test}{test}{\href {mailto:test}{test}}{test}
        \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{flushright}
            \cvref{test}{test}{\href {mailto:test}{test}}{test}
        \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}
\end{fullwidth}
  \medskip
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. I tried a tabular environment, but it won't let me use the cvref function within the cells.

Using minipages, I get the following result:
[image]

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]. You probably could use minipages.

Comment: We can't compile this without the class file

Comment: I updated the class file, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- your `fullwidth` environment does not adjust the `\textwidth`. However you can use `.33\linewidth` to automatically get the width of the minipages
- the `cvref` macro internally used a description, that's why it does not obey your attempts to center or left align. You can use the following redefinition to get a similar result, which will obey your alignment:

---

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{test}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=9cm,marginparwidth=6.8cm,marginparsep=1.2cm,top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm,footskip=2\baselineskip}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[default]{lato}
\definecolor{Mulberry}{HTML}{72243D}
\definecolor{SlateGrey}{HTML}{2E2E2E}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{666666}
\colorlet{heading}{Sepia}
\colorlet{accent}{Mulberry}
\colorlet{emphasis}{SlateGrey}
\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}
\renewcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\renewcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\cvref}[4]{%
  \smallskip
  \textcolor{emphasis}{\textbf{#1}}\par
  \smallskip\normalsize
  \ifstrequal{#2}{}{}{
  \textbf{\color{accent}#2}\par
  \smallskip}
%  \begin{description}[font=\color{accent},style=multiline,leftmargin=1.25em]
  {\color{accent}\small\normalfont\mailsymbol} #3\par
  {\color{accent}\small\normalfont\phonesymbol} #4\par
%  \end{description}
  \medskip
%   \medskip
}

\begin{document}

\begin{fullwidth}
    \cvsection{References}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
            \cvref{test}{test}{\href {mailto:test}{test}}{test}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
            \centering
            \cvref{test}{test}{\href {mailto:test}{test}}{test}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
        \raggedleft
            \cvref{test}{test}{\href {mailto:test}{test}}{test}
    \end{minipage}
\end{fullwidth}


\end{document}
```